# Polymorphism + Overloading - How to make a child class' polymorphic/overloaded method get called?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

I have a Shape and Square class:

```
public class Shape {..}
public class Square extends Shape {...}
```

I have a Parent and Child Class that have methods to work on Shape/Square:

```
public class Parent(){
    public void doSomething(Shape a){
        print("Parent doSomething called");
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent(){

    @Override
    public doSomething(Shape a){
        print("Child doSomething for SHAPE called");
    }


    public doSomething(Square a){
        print("Child doSomething for SQUARE called");
    }
}
```

Now, when i execute this:

```
Shape square = new Square();

Parent parent = new Child();

parent.doSomething(square);
```

As expected, "Child doSomething for SHAPE called" is the output.

Is there a way to get the "Child doSomething for **SQUARE** called" output, by pure polymorphism, without defining the **doSomething(Square a)** in Parent class and use @Override in child?

Needless to say, i am trying to avoid any if/else checks with instance of operator and extra castings.

Comment: The "pure" solution is double dispatch, which java doesn't implement. you can use the visitor pattern as a workaround.

Comment: @NathanHughes Is there any language that implements this? does C# implement this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to let each shape be responsible for printing/returning the message itself and that is :

```
class Shape {
    public String doSomething(){
        return "doSomething for SHAPE called";
    }
}

class Square extends Shape {
    @Override
    public String doSomething(){
        return "doSomething for SQUARE called";
    }
}
```

Here is your parent and child class :

```
class Parent{
public void doSomething(Shape a){
    System.out.println("Parent doSomething called");
        }
}

class Child extends Parent{

@Override
public void doSomething(Shape a){
            System.out.println("Child "+a.doSomething());
        }
}
```

**Execute :**

```
Shape square = new Square();
Parent parent = new Child();
parent.doSomething(square);
```

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

below works fine

```
public class PloyM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
        c.doSomething(new Shape());
        c.doSomething(new Square());
    }
}

class Shape { }
class Square extends Shape {}

class Parent {
    public void doSomething(Shape a){
        System.out.println("Parent doSomething called");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void doSomething(Shape a){
        System.out.println("Child doSomething for SHAPE called");
    }

    public void doSomething(Square a){
        System.out.println("Child doSomething for SQUARE called");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to make it work using the parent class and not this : Child c = new Child();

Comment: sry, missed that part - if you typed it as Parent - it can not know about the other doSomething(Square) - you have to refer to Child to see method doSomething(Square)